# What is the equivalent of document.getElementbyId in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

But this does not work:

```
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

I am looking for something like...

```
$('#map_canvas').toElementBlahblah?
```

Comment: What's the point of using jQuery to get the element if you're just going to get rid of the jQuery object? Just use the native method, or create a wrapper function if you want something shorter to type, like this: `function id(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }` then use it like this: `id("map_canvas")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`.get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
$('#map_canvas').get(0)
$('#map_canvas')[0]
```

---

Though, `document.getElementById` obviously has better performance - it is the method used internally by the jQuery core when querying the DOM for a single ID selector.

So then you're building a jQuery object just to discard it afterwards. Up to you whether to save some bytes in the bandwidth or microseconds in execution time.

Not much difference, honestly. I use the jQuery version when performance is not concerned and I'm lazy to type `document.getElementById`, though vanilla JS is a bit more logical in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
 $('#map_canvas').get(0);
 $('#map_canvas')[0]; // or direct property access
```

However, I can see no reason not to use `document.getElementById`.